# Simple Android App SQLite login

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, authentication

I have an on going issue with my SQLite login for my app.  I have a simple DBHandler class that has created a database, inside the database I have stored a single user:  Username: test Password: 1234

I also have a LogInScreen class that handles the view of the login and also will hold the methods to authenticate the login.

I want the user to enter their login details into the text fields and  when they press the login button to verify this against my database.  As you can see in the attached image.

[image]

I already have the username stored and this is my code

The code does work but as you can see in the LogInScreen class it is not checking against my database but the actual text fields.  Unfortunately I am completely new to SQLite and programming so I just can not figure it out.  Any help will be highly appreciated :)

```
package com.C05025.noughtsandcrosses;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DBHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "userDB.db";
private static final String TABLE_USERS = "users";

public static final String COLUMN_NAME = "name";
public static final String COLUMN_PASSWORD = "password";

public DBHandler(Context context, String name, CursorFactory factory,
        int version) {
    //super(context, name, factory, version);
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, factory, DATABASE_VERSION);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String CREATE_USER_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " +    TABLE_USERS + "("
               + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + COLUMN_NAME + " TEXT," 
               + COLUMN_PASSWORD + " INTEGER" + ")";
            db.execSQL(CREATE_USER_TABLE);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase arg0, int arg1, int arg2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void addUser(LogIn user) {

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(COLUMN_NAME, user.getName());
    values.put(COLUMN_PASSWORD, user.getPassword());

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    db.insert(TABLE_USERS, null, values);
    db.close();
}

public LogIn findUser(String Username) {
    String query = "Select * FROM " + TABLE_USERS + " WHERE " + COLUMN_NAME + " =  \"" +
      Username + "\"";

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);

    LogIn User = new LogIn();

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        User.setName(cursor.getString(1));
        User.setPassword(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(2)));
        cursor.close();
    } else {
        User = null;
    }
    db.close();
    return User;
}


}
```

LoginScreen Class:

```
    package com.C05025.noughtsandcrosses;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class LogInScreen extends Activity {
EditText txtUsername;
EditText txtPassword;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.loginscreen);
    txtUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditUsername);
    txtPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditPassword);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

public void newLogIn(View view) {

    if(txtUsername.getText().toString().equals("test") && 
            txtPassword.getText().toString().equals("1234")){
        Intent i = new Intent(LogInScreen.this, MainMenu.class);
         startActivity(i);              
         LogInScreen.this.finish();
            }
    else{
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wrong Credentials",
                  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();   
            }

                   }    
            }
```

Comment: Please don't duplicate your own questions, and try harder.

Comment: I completely new to this place and I tried to delete my other question but it won't let, I tried to make my issue a bit clearer in this post I am not trying to annoy anyone :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though I don't really understand the problem and I'd love to see the stacktrace, [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/) is a wonderful guide you can use on how to add login and registration to your application using SQLite, MySQL and PHP.